# Add Manager to bottom of BlackBerry Screen

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am trying to create a layout as show in the image attached here:

[image]

Here are my screen components,

1. Screen title field
2. Button at the center of screen
3. `HorizontalFieldManager` containing 3 buttons docked to bottom of screen
4. Add banner, placed as docked below.

I have completed all of the 1, 2 and 4. I have used setStatus(Field) to place the ad banner. Also, I have customized the `HorizontalFieldManager` for holding 3 fields justified aligned. Now I don't know how could I place it to the bottom of screen just above the add banner, as I've already used setStatus() for the ad banner.  Also, if the virtual keyboard comes up, I want it to cover up the bottom of the screen, rather than push the HorizonalFieldManager and ad banner up.

Comment: requirements need to be fully spelled out in your question, not just in the title.  I've edited the text to incorporate your comments, and what is in the title, as well as my best guess for why you don't want to use setStatus().

Comment: Please post your existing code. Basically, you have to create a `VerticalFieldManager`, override its `sublayout()` method and add it to the screen's delegate. Than, all your other fields and managers should be added to the new VFM instead to the screen's delegate. Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9549827/396949), it will help you to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use setstatus for adding banner stuff instead you can use two horizontal managers at bottom of screen considering Display.getHeight().

I ve done similar kind of screen in my application here is the brief info regarding that.

1) parent Manager (either Vertical/Horizontal) say parentManager

2) Two Horozontal managers with appropriate height and Maximum width (override in sublayout of horizontal managers) and add both these two a verticalfield manager(bottommanager)

3) then here comes tricky part. To the parent Manger override sublayout and add these steps

```
vfm_screen = new VerticalFieldManager(ScrollView.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | HORIZONTAL_SCROLL
                | NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL){

            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                setPositionChild(parentManager, 0, 0);
                layoutChild(parentManager, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
                setPositionChild(bottommanager, 0, Display.getHeight()-114);
                layoutChild(bottommanager, Display.getWidth(), 114);
                setExtent(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
            };
        };

vfm_screen.add(parentManager);

vfm_screen.add(bottommanager);

add(vfm_screen);
```

Here 114 is hard sized and you can **change** it based on your requirement. and adding Button to that parent manger at center of screen.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the ad-banner and the 3 justified fields with a VerticalFieldManager, then pass the combined manager to setStatus().

Comment: LOL, I have already done that. here are 2 problems, 1. the VFM I am adding is getting white background. 2. set status takes the field up to make it visible always when virtual keyboard opens. so that won't serve my problem.

Comment: also, if you read my question I have clearly told without using setStatus.

Comment: I've read your question several times now, and I don't see any mention of wanting to avoid setStatus.  In fact, you already say you're using it, and didn't mention any virtual keyboard requirements.   I can't read your mind.